# How to get the line number and character position of regex match with VS Code's API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I know how to get the position of the cursor:

```
editor.selection.active
```

This will yield something like: `{ _character: 4, _line 1 }`

Now, I'd like to match a character or word (in the active editor) and get it's line number and character position:

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
let text = editor.document.getText()
const match = text.match(/match/)

// What should I write here?
```

How to get the line number and character position of the match (or first match)?

I couldn't find anything on Google or VS Code API's documentation.

Comment: Do you want this for the first match only or for all matches?

Comment: @Mark Just the first match for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the methods from [TextDocument](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument)

- `positionAt(offset: number): Position`
  Converts a zero-based offset to a position.

The `match` has an offset (start of match).

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the lines of your document, and count the line number:

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
let lines = editor.document.getText().split(“\n”);

for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    const match = lines[i].match(/match/);
    if (match)
    {
        let char = match[1].index;
        let lineNb = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: why write it yourself if VSC TextDocument already has the methods for this